# How to change the DEFAULT C++ Language with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've read about how to change these settings in .props files for VS 2019, but those solutions didn't work for me with VS 2022.

I simply want the DEFAULT C++ Language Standard to be CPP20, not CPP14.

I don't like having to change it for every project as sometimes I forget and thus my code won't run.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 1):

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/configuring-your-compiler-choosing-a-language-standard/

Setting a language standard in Visual Studio

As of the time of writing, Visual Studio 2022 defaults to C++14 capabilities, which does not allow for the use of newer features introduced in C++17 and C++20.

To use these newer features, you’ll need to enable a newer language standard. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do this globally -- you must do so on a project-by-project basis.

Warning

With Visual Studio, you will need to reselect your language standard every time you create a new project.

To select a language standard, open your project, then go to Project menu > (Your application’s Name) Properties, then open Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language.